# background service in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter I create a login page and home screen
but I went also create a background service to check if any changes in database to create push notifications and the application immediately wen start the system
thank you

Comment: can you post the code so that it will be clear what's going wrong with you app

Comment: i don't now how to create a backgroud service in flutter